# Html Helper Extensions not being found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I'm using the release version of ASP.net MVC and I seem to be getting this error a lot

```
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' and no extension method 'RenderPartial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

which is very odd since I can browse to System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper and all the extension methods are there.  Even stranger is that I can compile and all the errors go away, however as soon as I start editing again they show back up.  I am including

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
```

in my site.master file which I found suggested somewhere but that doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas?  The intelisense isn't finding the extension methods either.

Answer (score 4):

First, check if you are using RenderPartial method right:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial(...); %>
```

Second, check your web.config contains:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use

`<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", ViewData); %>`

or

`<%=Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Project/Projects.ascx", ViewData); %>`

?

it's supposed to be the first one, without "=".
I'm not sure if that will solve it but I remember they changed something that way.

Comment: It is just the standard site.master which comes with a new project  
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>

Answer (score 0):

Also see: ['System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' - ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780097/system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-renderpartial-a)

You may think this is dumb, but I just had the same problem. I had a working MVC app, running 1.0.0.0 and all of a sudden it stopped working giving me the same RenderPartial isn't in the definition. Well it turns out that while I was going crazy cleaning up my web.config, I removed this section.  When I re-added it, everything worked again. I'm sure this has something to do with how the class extensions load during runtime.

Anyway, re-adding this to my web.config worked on my machine. ;)

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                     type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>

        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4"
                     type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```