# asp.net mvc deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ive managed to get asp.net mvc up and running on an iis6 server, but  I keep getting silly messages like  'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial'

I've got all the required dlls and even installed mvc from
 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en

any clues about what Im missing?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`RenderPartial` is an extension method and is defined in `System.Web.Mvc`.

So check out if you have in root **Web.config** lines adding `System.Web.Extensions` assembly:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

in `<configuration> <system.web> <compilation> <assemblies>` node.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions and also more importantly for your contributions which has made this site the great site. I dont know what I would do without this site and you guys. Thanks

this link fixed it, replacing the compilers section of the web config did it ['System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial' - ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780097/system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-renderpartial-a)

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably missing this from your web.config:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
```