# HTML helpers not available in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a partial view and can't access the Html namespace for HTML Helpers. It's available in the main view. Am I missing something?

[image]

**EDIT:** I should mention that I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876412/html-helper-extensions-not-being-found)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I don't see how it's relevant to my question.

Comment: Where does your view located at?

Comment: In a sub of Views. Does it matter?

Comment: It can matter, also [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper) contains some advice. Or try to restart Visual Studio, sometimes it runs into crazy state...

Comment: How are you accessing HtmlHelper from your partial view? Can we see the code?

Comment: All of the code is in the screenshot. @Html has the cursor next to it and the intellisense dropdown is active.

Comment: If you add it to the View using the @using as it appears in the screenshot, I would restart VS. Not sure if you try that yet. Just thinking out loud.

Comment: also, how did you add the namespace? (i.e. web.config)

Comment: Could you try the answer suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5557503/350933

Comment: You better add the namespace of the helper into the web.config that resides in the views folder and the one in the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

check is there a web.config in you views directory 
and in the web.config

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```